# How to copy files from Amazon EFS to my local machine with shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I have a question regarding file transfer from Amazon efs to my local machine with a simple shell script. The manual procedure I follow is:

- Copy the file from efs to my Amazon ec2 instance using sudo cp
- Copy from ec2 to my local machine using scp or FileZilla (drag and drop)

Is there a way it can be done running a shell script in which I give two inputs: source file address and save destination directory?

Can two steps be reduced to one i.e. directly copying from efs to local machine?

Comment: I got the answer to this! I can directly save content from efs to local machine using scp -i keyFile -r usernamer@ec2ip:directory_to_copy_from  directory_to_copy_to

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount to the local machine and access the remote file system locally on your machine.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html

With mounting, you can access the file locally with your machine resources to edit the remote files.

While SCP can work, you need to keep them in sync all the time between your local and remote.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to keep them in sync?

Comment: Mounting would be the clean way to do it. So you can access remote files in your local file system. If you maintain your files with a version control such as git you can go back in history to see if you want to go back with your changes.  If you prefer to sync the files back and forth, you can use rsync with cron, so it updates remote files with local changes on periodic basis.